# What is the puffy bread shown in Chitty Chitty Bang Bang?

Tags: bread, food-identification

My son is infatuated with the movie "Chitty Chitty Bang Bang," and there's a delicious looking bread shown in a breakfast scene.  It looks like a giant popover about the size of Dick Van Dyke's head (see below.)  What is it?

[image: Chitty Chitty Bang Bang bread]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably a [Cottage Loaf.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cottage_loaf) It used to be common in England when there were independent bakeries. It's not seen so much now.

Comment: The movie does take place in England, and it looks a lot like the image in the Wikipedia page.  However, the Wikipedia page also links to the brioche page, which looks even more like the movie bread to me.

Comment: Brioche wouldn't have been common among the working classes of England in the era in which the film is set. To me the version in the film looks like a less crusty white loaf.

Comment: I agree it seems like it would have been an anachronism if it were really brioche.  All I know is that I want to cut into it and eat it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a cottage loaf which was a crusty bread with a fluffy interior.

It was very popular in bakery's in England & was indeed a tasty and impressive loaf, since the rise of the evil supermarkets such loaves are a rare sight.
Probably they are put off by the strange shape, preferring rectangle loaves's which are easier to cut & store.